# Inverting a dictionary with sets/lists as values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have written a function to invert a dictionary (checked against many other StackExchange posts about similar tasks) whose keys are strings and whose values are sets (of strings):

```
def invert_dict(d: Dict[str, set]) -> Dict[str, set]:
    """
    Returns inverted dictionary (with original dictionary, d, whose keys are
    strings and values are sets containing strings of which occur in the
    keys of d).

    Useful for indexing graph in opposite direction (i.e., values inbound to
    key vs. values outbound to key).
    """
    inverse_dict = dict.fromkeys(d, set())
    for key in d.keys():
        for item in d[key]:
            inverse_dict[item].add(key)

    return inverse_dict
```

What I am finding to be completely mind-boggling is that adding a string to *one* value/set (associated with *one particular* key) actually adds said string to *all* values/sets in the resultant dictionary!

Per the code above, the troublemaking line is `inverse_dict[item].add(key)`.

For example, consider the following dictionary:

```
original_dict = {'4.html': {'2.html'}, 
                 '3.html': {'4.html', '2.html'}, 
                 '2.html': {'3.html', '1.html'}, 
                 '1.html': {'2.html'}}
```

When I add `print` statements before and after `inverse_dict[item].add(key)` and run `invert_dict(original_dict)`, I get the following printed to console:

```
Adding 4.html to the set associated with 2.html
{'4.html': {'4.html'}, '3.html': {'4.html'}, '2.html': {'4.html'}, '1.html': {'4.html'}}

Adding 3.html to the set associated with 4.html
{'4.html': {'3.html', '4.html'}, '3.html': {'3.html', '4.html'}, '2.html': {'3.html', '4.html'}, '1.html': {'3.html', '4.html'}}

Adding 3.html to the set associated with 2.html
{'4.html': {'3.html', '4.html'}, '3.html': {'3.html', '4.html'}, '2.html': {'3.html', '4.html'}, '1.html': {'3.html', '4.html'}}

Adding 2.html to the set associated with 3.html
{'4.html': {'3.html', '4.html', '2.html'}, '3.html': {'3.html', '4.html', '2.html'}, '2.html': {'3.html', '4.html', '2.html'}, '1.html': {'3.html', '4.html', '2.html'}}

Adding 2.html to the set associated with 1.html
{'4.html': {'3.html', '4.html', '2.html'}, '3.html': {'3.html', '4.html', '2.html'}, '2.html': {'3.html', '4.html', '2.html'}, '1.html': {'3.html', '4.html', '2.html'}}

Adding 1.html to the set associated with 2.html
{'4.html': {'1.html', '3.html', '4.html', '2.html'}, '3.html': {'1.html', '3.html', '4.html', '2.html'}, '2.html': {'1.html', '3.html', '4.html', '2.html'}, '1.html': {'1.html', '3.html', '4.html', '2.html'}}
```

What gives? I have tried replacing `d.keys()` with `d.items()` and using lists instead of sets, but the results were the same.

I am using Python 3.7.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dict.fromkeys(d, set())` just creates one `set` and puts that in every dictionary entry. You need to create a new set for each entry:

```
inverse_dict = {k: set() for k in d}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Barmar! Was just reading this as you answered (from Python docs): "All of the values refer to just a single instance, so it generally doesn’t make sense for value to be a mutable object such as an empty list. To get distinct values, use a dict comprehension instead." How embarrassing. :/